# Fragment factory with dialog fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

Is it okey to instantiate a dialog fragment with FragmentFactory ?

```
baseActivity.fragmentFactoryImpl.title = title
val testFragment=
            baseActivity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
                baseActivity.classLoader, TestFragmentDialog::class.java.name
            ) as DialogFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use [Jetpack Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

Easy way to manipulate with Fragments and actions between them

The other way is to create MyDialogFragment class and instantiate it where needed. Doc [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs)

Answer (score 0):

FragmentFactory Interface used to control the instantiation of Fragment instances. Implementations can be registered with a FragmentManager via setFragmentFactory.

Useful if you want to initialize the fragment with a custom parameter.

When I look at your code, you don't provide a use case that would require using the fragment Factory.

Comment: I found this;You must set a custom FragmentFactory if you want to use a non-default constructor to ensure that your constructor is called when the fragment is re-instantiated.  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#DialogFragment()

Comment: As I said, if you are passing parameters, I suggest you use it.

Comment: I see but the main problem is casting it to dialog fragment,because fragmentfactory returns a fragment not dialogfragment. Is it the right way ?

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 28. Use the Support Library DialogFragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle. DialogFragment is also a fragment.